# Data-attributes with html editor for mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Data Attributes for editor for not working.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SireTag, new { data_typeahead = "dsfsdfsd" })
```

When i open my chrome browser i cant see any data-attribute for my text box.
I tried goggling and have not found any thing useful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The second `object` parameter for `Html.EditorFor` isn't for HTML attributes, it's for additional view data. The `EditorFor` helpers don't allow customizing HTML attributes in the way that e.g. the more specific `<input>` helpers do - they take most of their setup from model metadata (for example `[Attributes]`).

Easiest way to "fix" is obviously dropping `EditorFor`:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SireTag, new { data_typeahead = "dsfsdfsd" })
```

Alternatively, write your own EditorTemplate for the property. This could allow you to use (or simplify) your original syntax, by retrieving the `data_typeahead` value from `ViewData["data_typeahead"]` (or "typeahead").

One step further, more advanced, you could make your own `Attribute` to apply to your model properties + your own `ModelMetadataProvider` (or - simpler - use `IMetadataAware`, more on that below) to turn it into metadata that the EditorTemplate could use - this in order to remove the decision about `data-` attributes entirely from your View, turning your call into:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SireTag)
```

... and your model into something like:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Typeahead("dsfsdfsd")]
    public string SireTag { get; set; }
}
```

Example of this approach using IMetadataAware:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class TypeaheadAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware
{
    private readonly string value;

    public TypeaheadAttribute(string value)
    {
       this.value = value;
    }

    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.AdditionalValues["typeahead"] = value;
    }
}
```

This metadata entry can then be extracted in the EditorTemplate, using `ViewContext.ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues` (a dictionary) and the result be added to an attributes dictionary passed to e.g. `Html.TextBox`.

Comment: While this solution works, @MarosDimitrio has posted an overload of the `EditorFor` method that accepts HTML attributes.

Comment: That link at the end of this answer appears now to be broken.

Comment: @ChrisFox - replaced the link with a simple example + explanation of what the link discussed - even though the top voted answer should be preferred for this specific question, at least this shows the approach when more is needed. I haven't used this approach to editors for years, but the example should be reasonably correct.

Answer (score 33):

Actually you **can** use EditorFor and send additional HTML attributes. Use this [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406462%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and set the `additionalViewData` parameters. It expects an object with a `htmlAttributes` property:

```c#
@Html.EditorFor(
    model => model.SireTag,
    new { 
        htmlAttributes = new { data_typeahead = "dsfsdfsd" }
    }
)
```

This will generate something like:

```html
<input id="SireTag" name="SireTag" ... data-typeahead="dsfsdfsd">
```

Comment: This should definitely be the answer.