# Min and Max limits for Html.EditorFor(DateTime)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to set a minimum and maximum selectable date/datetime for Html.EditorFor?

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)
```

If yes, how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data-attributes with html editor for mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177335/data-attributes-with-html-editor-for-mvc)

Comment: Depends on your version of MVC.  It seems to change each version, but this has been an option for many years, so likely what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22556424/2181514

Answer (score 2):

I looked into the suggestions in comments and it worked (kindof) by using the [DataType(DataType.DateTime)] attribute on the model property in combination with

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @min= "2021-05-19" } })
```

However that gave me issues with formatting and submitting my form.. i ended up handling the date validation in the controller..